# How can I write a query that returns "between" to return alphabetic data, not just numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Daily_account` table:

```
customer_id    account_id            current_balance

1                 D1                       200
2                 d2                       300
3                 d10                      400
4                 d100                     500
5                 d101                     600
```

Now I have a query:

```
select customer_id,account_id,current_balance
from daily_account
where account_id between 'D1' and'D100'
```

It is giving me output of account no of D1,D10,D100, but I want to get output of every no.
How to get output of every account which comes between D1 and d100?

Comment: Please give a sample of the output you're expecting.

Comment: The account_id is a string, not a number, so it's using string collation, instead of numeric collation.  If all your account numbers start with a letter, then you can trim off the letter, and cast the remaining string to a number.  But that won't work if your account ids mix letters and numbers in unpredictable patterns.  Do all your account numbers start with a single letter, followed by only digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some more research i found one function that is cast function it give me the answer....

```
select  customer_id, account_id,current_balance  from daily_account 
where cast(right(Account_id,(length(account_id)-1)) AS unsigned) 
between '1' and'100'
```

Comment: You tagged your question `sql-server` while this answer is likely MySQL. The idea of this solution is clear, though, and should be easy to port to SQL Server, but if you are not actually using SQL Server, but are using MySQL instead, you should have tagged your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The between statement in the above snippet is working with string, which is different from number ordering.

In case that the account_id always starts with 'D' we can remove it and cast it to a number:

```
SELECT *
, REPLACE(account_id, 'd','0') // just replace
, CAST( REPLACE(account_id, 'd','0') as int) // now convert to int
FROM daily_account
```

and to use it in between, use it like this

```
SELECT customer_id,account_id,current_balance
FROM daily_account
WHERE 
CAST( REPLACE(account_id, 'd','0') as int) between 1 and 100
```

Answer (score 1):

If all starts with one char you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT customer_id
     , CAST(REPLACE(account_id,'d','') AS int) account_id
     , current_balance
FROM daily_account) tbl
WHERE account_id between '1' and'100'
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to remove the non-numeric in the account_id like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Daily_account WHERE CAST(REPLACE(account_id,'D','') AS INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_id,account_id,current_balance
from daily_account
where CAST(replace(account_id, 'D', '') as int) between 1 and 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to imply that you want the solution to work with various prefixes, not just `'D'`. If that is the case, please consider the following alternative:

```
SELECT customer_id, account_id, current_balance
FROM daily_account
WHERE STUFF(account_id, 1, 1, '') between 1 and 100
;
```

The above is SQL Server, but since your answer also seems to imply you are using MySQL, here's a MySQL equivalent for you:

```
SELECT customer_id, account_id, current_balance
FROM daily_account
WHERE INSERT(account_id, 1, 1, '') between 1 and 100
;
```